# Interpolation using ExponentialSmoothing from stats models

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, holtwinters

I am using `ExponentialSmoothing` from statsmodels to run Holt-Winters method on time series.
I get forecasted values but can not extract calculated values and compare them with observed values.

```
from pandas import Series
from scipy import stats
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing

modelHW = ExponentialSmoothing(np.asarray(passtrain_df['n_passengers']), seasonal_periods=12, trend='add', seasonal='mul',).fit()

y_hat_avg['Holt_Winter'] = modelHW.forecast(prediction_size)
```

So here, `prediction_size = number of forecasted datapoints` (4 in my case)
`passtrain_df` is a dataframe with observations (140 datapoints) based on which Holt_Winter model is built (regression).

I can easily display 4 forecasted values.

How do I extract 140 calculated values?

Tried to use:

```
print(ExponentialSmoothing.predict(np.asarray(passtrain_df), start=0, end=139))
```

But I probably have a syntax error somewhere

Thank you!

Comment: I've just fixed the x-axis time format to represent the format of the original data.

Comment: @vestland - there is still an error regretfully - --------------------
NameErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-86f5607eaa8e> in <module>()
     22 # Plot
     23 fig, ax = plt.subplots()
---> 24 myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')
     25 df_all.plot(ax = ax, x_compat=True)
     26 ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

NameError: name 'mdates' is not defined

Comment: What matplotlib version are you running? run `matplotlib.__version__` and check. I'm on `2.2.2`

Comment: And I see you've got something called `Plot 23` in your error message there. If you're just adding parts of my code on top of your own code, It moght not work. Try a fresh start with *only* the code I provided to see if it works with mdates. And in any case, make sure to add this line at the beginning of your code `import matplotlib.dates as mdates`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

- Replaced synthetic dataset with sample data from OP
- Fixed function that builds new forecast period
- Fixed x-axis date format as per OPs request

**Answer:**

If you're looking for calculated values within your estimation period, you should use `modelHW.fittedvalues` and not `modelHW.forecast()`. The latter will give you just what it says; forecasts. And it's pretty awesome. Let me show you how to do both things:

**Plot 1 - Model within estimation period**

[image]

**Plot 2 - Forecasts**

[image]

**Code:**

```
#imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
#%%
#

# Load data
pass_df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dacatay/time-series-analysis/master/data/passengers.csv', sep=';')
pass_df = pass_df.set_index('month')
type(pass_df.index)

df = pass_df.copy()

# Model
modelHW = ExponentialSmoothing(np.asarray(df['n_passengers']), seasonal_periods=12, trend='add', seasonal='mul',).fit()
modelHW.summary()

# Model, fitted values
model_values = modelHW.fittedvalues
model_period = df.index
df_model = pd.concat([df['n_passengers'], pd.Series(model_values, index = model_period)], axis = 1)
df_model.columns = ['n_passengers', 'HWmodel']
df_model = df_model.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df_model.index))

# Model, plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')
df_model.plot(ax = ax, x_compat=True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

# Forecasts
prediction_size = 10
forecast_values = modelHW.forecast(prediction_size)

# Forecasts, build new period 
forecast_start = df.index[-1]
forecast_start = pd.to_datetime(forecast_start, format='%Y-%m-%d')
forecast_period = pd.period_range(forecast_start, periods=prediction_size+1, freq='M')
forecast_period = forecast_period[1:]

# Forecasts, create dataframe
df_forecast = pd.Series(forecast_values, index = forecast_period.values).to_frame()
df_forecast.columns = ['HWforecast']

# merge input and forecast dataframes
df_all = pd.merge(df,df_forecast, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
#df_all = df_all.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df_all.index.values))
ix = df_all.index
ixp = pd.PeriodIndex(ix, freq = 'M')
df_all = df_all.set_index(ixp)

# Forecast, plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')
df_all.plot(ax = ax, x_compat=True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
```

---

**Previous attempts:**

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing

# Data that matches your setup, but with a random
# seed to make it reproducible
np.random.seed(42)

# Time
date = pd.to_datetime("1st of Jan, 2019")
dates = date+pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(140), 'D')

# Data
n_passengers = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=5.0, size=140).cumsum()
n_passengers = n_passengers.astype(int) + 100
df = pd.DataFrame({'n_passengers':n_passengers},index=dates)
```

**1. How to plot observed vs. estimated values within the estimation period:**

The following snippet will extract all fitted values and plot it against your observed values.

**Snippet 2:**

```
# Model
modelHW = ExponentialSmoothing(np.asarray(df['n_passengers']), seasonal_periods=12, trend='add', seasonal='mul',).fit()
modelHW.summary()

# Model, fitted values
model_values = modelHW.fittedvalues
model_period = df.index
df_model = pd.concat([df['n_passengers'], pd.Series(model_values, index = model_period)], axis = 1)
df_model.columns = ['n_passengers', 'HWmodel']
df_model.plot()
```

**Plot 1:**

[image]

**2. How to produce and plot model forecasts of a certain length:**

The following snippet will produce 10 forecasts from your model, and plot it as an extended period compared to your observer values.

**Snippet 3:**

```
# Forecast
prediction_size = 10
forecast_values = modelHW.forecast(prediction_size)
forecast_period = df.index[-1] + pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(prediction_size+1), 'D')
forecast_period  = forecast_period[1:]

df_forecast = pd.concat([df['n_passengers'], pd.Series(forecast_values, index = forecast_period)], axis = 1)
df_forecast.columns = ['n_passengers', 'HWforecast']
df_forecast.plot()
```

**Plot 2:**

[image]

---

**And here's the whole thing for an easy copy&paste:**

```
# imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing

# Data that matches your setup, but with a random
# seed to make it reproducible
np.random.seed(42)

# Time
date = pd.to_datetime("1st of Jan, 2019")
dates = date+pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(140), 'D')

# Data
n_passengers = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=5.0, size=140).cumsum()
n_passengers = n_passengers.astype(int) + 100
df = pd.DataFrame({'n_passengers':n_passengers},index=dates)

# Model
modelHW = ExponentialSmoothing(np.asarray(df['n_passengers']), seasonal_periods=12, trend='add', seasonal='mul',).fit()
modelHW.summary()

# Model, fitted values
model_values = modelHW.fittedvalues
model_period = df.index
df_model = pd.concat([df['n_passengers'], pd.Series(model_values, index = model_period)], axis = 1)
df_model.columns = ['n_passengers', 'HWmodel']
df_model.plot()

# Forecast
prediction_size = 10
forecast_values = modelHW.forecast(prediction_size)
forecast_period = df.index[-1] + pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(prediction_size+1), 'D')
forecast_period  = forecast_period[1:]

df_forecast = pd.concat([df['n_passengers'], pd.Series(forecast_values, index = forecast_period)], axis = 1)
df_forecast.columns = ['n_passengers', 'HWforecast']
df_forecast.plot()
```

@vestland - here is the code and error:

```
y_train = passtrain_df.copy(deep=True)

model_HW = ExponentialSmoothing(np.asarray(y_train['n_passengers']), seasonal_periods=12, trend='add', seasonal='mul',).fit()

model_values = model_HW.fittedvalues
model_period = y_train.index

hw_model = pd.concat([y_train['n_passengers'], pd.Series(model_values, index = model_period)], axis = 1)
hw_model.columns = ['Observed Passengers', 'Holt-Winters']

plt.figure(figsize=(18,12))
hw_model.plot()

forecast_values = model_HW.forecast(prediction_size)
forecast_period = y_train.index[-1] + pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(prediction_size+1),'D')
forecast_period  = forecast_period[1:]

hw_forecast = pd.concat([y_train['n_passengers'], pd.Series(forecast_values, index = forecast_period)], axis = 1)
hw_forecast.columns = ['Observed Passengers', 'HW-Forecast']
hw_forecast.plot()
```

Error:

```
NullFrequencyError     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-5f37a0dd0cfa> in <module>()
     17 
     18 forecast_values = model_HW.forecast(prediction_size)
---> 19 forecast_period = y_train.index[-1] +  pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(prediction_size+1),'D')
     20 forecast_period  = forecast_period[1:]
     21 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimelike.py in __radd__(self, other)
    879         def __radd__(self, other):
    880             # alias for __add__
--> 881             return self.__add__(other)
    882         cls.__radd__ = __radd__
    883 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimelike.py in __add__(self, other)
    842                 # This check must come after the check for  np.timedelta64
    843                 # as is_integer returns True for these
--> 844                 result = self.shift(other)
    845 
    846             # array-like others

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimelike.py in shift(self, n, freq)
   1049 
   1050         if self.freq is None:
-> 1051             raise NullFrequencyError("Cannot shift with no freq")
   1052 
   1053         start = self[0] + n * self.freq

NullFrequencyError: Cannot shift with no freq
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the delay. The first part worked really well (modelHW.fittedvalues) The issue is with the 2nd portion (forecast) I am getting an error: - see above. Can not properly format here. It is also not clear why do you suggest use "D" while the data has monthly frequency. However I tried "M" but got the same error

Comment: forecast_values = model_HW.forecast(prediction_size)
    forecast_period = y_train.index[-1] +pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(prediction_size+1),'D')
    forecast_period  = forecast_period[1:]
    hw_forecast = pd.concat([y_train['n_passengers'], pd.Series(forecast_values,  index = forecast_period)], axis = 1)
    hw_forecast.columns = ['Observed Passengers', 'HW-Forecast']
    hw_forecast.plot()

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I can set up a chatroom tomorrow and we can take it from there.

Comment: sure! be happy to! I provided the code and the error

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your real world dataset? The numbers are not important, but the structure and index is.

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dacatay/time-series-analysis/master/data/passengers.csv

Comment: this is the extraction command: pass_df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dacatay/time-series-analysis/master/data/passengers.csv',
                      header=0, parse_dates=True, sep=';')

Comment: @Toly, the code in my latest edit will work on your sample data. I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks! Will try over the weekend and will assign the score. One more question: X axes do not plot values (in this case like "1950-02". I tried many ways including xticks with np.arange(start, finish, stepwise) but can get those data labels displayed in a good way (either like in your case just says month or a date OR lists everything so it is unreadable). Any idea?

Comment: @Toly, I'll fix it over the weekend

Comment: I tried the following: fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(18,12))

ax.plot(df_all)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plticker.MultipleLocator(x_step)). It worked in the first part of the code (fittedvalues) but for some reason does not work on forecast. x_step = min(int(num_values/10+0.5), 12) where num_values is the number of total observations

Comment: It gives the error:  Period('1961-01', 'M') is not a string for the command:   ax.plot(df-all)

Comment: the latest code generates an error - --------------------
NameErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-86f5607eaa8e> in <module>()
     22 # Plot
     23 fig, ax = plt.subplots()
---> 24 myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')
     25 df_all.plot(ax = ax, x_compat=True)
     26 ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

NameError: name 'mdates' is not defined

Comment: I made a little adjustment and it works now - # Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,12))
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')
df_all.plot(ax = ax, x_compat=True)
#ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plticker.MultipleLocator(x_step))

ax.grid(True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(bymonth=range(0,12,6)))
fig.autofmt_xdate()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

# rotates and right aligns the x labels, and moves the bottom of the
# axes up to make room for them
fig.autofmt_xdate()

Comment: Sounds cool! Please share a screenshot of your final plot! I'm curious...